# How do I use a class compiled by babel in a node project?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

Here is a very simple class that I'm testing written in es2015:

```
"use strict";

class Car {
    constructor(color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}

export default Car;
```

I use babel-cli to transpile that class so it can be used in node...this is the output:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var Car = function Car(color) {
    _classCallCheck(this, Car);

    this.color = color;
};

exports.default = Car;
```

In my node project I include that module like this:

```
var Car = require("js-models/lib/Car");
```

But when I do the following I get a "Car is not a function" error:

```
var blueCar = new Car('blue');
```

I'm running node v5.8 if that makes a difference in this case?

Comment: Did you try var Car = require("js-models/lib/Car");? Without the .Car? You use default export so .Car will be undefined.

Comment: That was a typo on my question. The actual code didn't have the .Car at the end and even without it, it still doesn't work :s Good catch though

Comment: have you tried not transpiling and using babel-node instead?

Comment: Check the version as the latest version of Babel gives the following end: `exports["default"] = Car; module.exports = exports["default"];`

Comment: THAT was the problem stdob

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports This module solved my problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can `import` default from module in ES and transpile them:

```
import Car from 'js-models/lib/Car';
let blueCar = new Car('blue');
```

2) You can export `Car` class, transpile and `require`:

```
// module js-models/lib/Car
"use strict";

export class Car {
    constructor(color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}

// node project
var Car = require("js-models/lib/Car").Car;    
var blueCar = new Car('blue');
```